# Is there a way to aggregate PostgreSQL trigger's "FOR EACH STATEMENT"

Tags: postgresql, trigger

In the documentation of PostgreSQL's triggers
[Example 43.7. Auditing with Transition Tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    empname           text NOT NULL,
    salary            integer
);

CREATE TABLE emp_audit(
    operation         char(1)   NOT NULL,
    stamp             timestamp NOT NULL,
    userid            text      NOT NULL,
    empname           text      NOT NULL,
    salary integer
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_emp_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_audit$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit
                SELECT 'I', now(), user, n.* FROM new_table n;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$emp_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
  
CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit_ins
    AFTER INSERT ON emp
    REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
    FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION process_emp_audit();
```

Every statement triggers data change. Basically the log table gets 1 new rows for every inserted row.

Is there a way to count all inserts as 1 transaction? Say inserting 1000 rows into the table to result into 1 record in the audit table?

Edit for the comments:

I consider this to be a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO emp(empname, salary)
SELECT 'test string', i
FROM generate_series(1, 1000) as x(i);
```

But it creates 1000 entries in the audit table(emp_audit).

Comment: If the 1000 rows are inserted with a single statement, the trigger will only fire once. You can then either aggregate those 1000 rows inside the trigger or only take the latest one

Answer (score 1):

I changed the trigger function to the following and it inserts just a single record after the load is finished:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_emp_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_audit$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit VALUES('I', now(), 4, 'postgres', NULL);
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$emp_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```